# How to setup geany on mac to compile fortran (beginner)

Tags: macos, compilation, fortran, geany

I'm trying to compile a script in fortran for my thesis. I'm working on a mac and I've installed gfortran. I've installed geany then and it's ok. I think to have a setup problem because, when I write or open my code (.f90 extension), I get different errors as:

> gfortran -Wall -o "xxx" "xxx.f90" (nel direttorio: /Users/.../project)
>
> Build failed. (translation from it)
>
> /bin/sh: gfortran: command not found

Why? Where I'm wrong? How can I solve?

If I try to execute directly i get:

> ./geany_run_script.sh: line 5: ./xxx: No such file or
> directory
>
> ------------------ (program exited with code: 127) Press return to continue

Comment: Looks like `gfortran` is not in your `PATH`. Can you post the output of `echo $PATH`?. The second error comes from the fact that you did not compile `xxx.f90` so `xxx` does not exist, so you can safely ignore that for now.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thank You.. in fact I've reinstalled gfortran and now all works properly! Thank You.. :)

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Kyle Kanos wrote:

> Looks like `gfortran` is not in your `PATH`. Can you post the output of `echo $PATH`?. The second error comes from the fact that you did not compile `xxx.f90` so `xxx` does not exist, so you can safely ignore that for now.

The OP Wrote:

> I've reinstalled gfortran and now all works properly!